# Mysql query return BLOB with Union Join

Tags: mysql, blob, union

When I run a Union query in mysql some values return as BLOB, is there a way to fix this?
I union the query because i want the sum of  specific columns to be at the bottom

```
select a.app_file_id,a.app_trn,a.app_fname,a.app_lname,l.computer_interest,l.loan_life,l.app_ln_amnt, l.commit_date,l.app_amnt_owed,r.amount_paid
from applicant a
left join loan l on   l.l_app_file_id=a.app_file_id
left join receipt r on r.r_app_file_id=l.l_app_file_id
WHERE l.app_loan_type=r.receipt_loan_type
AND l.app_loan_type='Computer Loan'
AND  MONTHNAME(commit_date) = 'April'
and YEAR(commit_date)=2012

Union
Select '', '','','','','',SUM(l.app_ln_amnt),'',SUM(l.app_amnt_owed),SUM(r.amount_paid)
from applicant a
left join loan l on   l.l_app_file_id=a.app_file_id
left join receipt r on r.r_app_file_id=l.l_app_file_id
WHERE l.app_loan_type=r.receipt_loan_type
AND l.app_loan_type='Computer Loan'
AND  MONTHNAME(commit_date) = 'April'
and YEAR(commit_date)=2012
```

Comment: What is coming back as BLOB?  What are the schemas?

Comment: The colums that are returning blob are; s_app_trn which is INT(9),computer_interest which is Double,loan_life which is int(11) and commit_date which is DATE

Answer (score 2):

In the first query of the UNION, the second column is an INT, while in the second query, it is an empty string, which isn't a valid INT.  Similarly for the 5th, 6th and 8th columns.

Comment: So you R saying I should put an INT in it? and what about the Date column

Comment: To avoid a BLOB, the types of the values in a column need to match.  Dates can be specified as strings, but must be in year-month-day format.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks for the explanation based on you explanation i had provided an example below, if there is something that can be improvised please do it.

Answer (score 0):

one easy way to avoid blob in union is by using format. consider the following examples

EG:

```
select "string 1","string 2","string 3" from dual
union
select "string 1",format(sum(1+2),0),"string 3" from dual
```

but i wouldn't recommend so. Make the result column types exact identical across all union and avoid using format to avoid "BLOB" in result

```
select "string 1",0 "string 2","string 3" from dual
union
select "string 1",sum(1+2),"string 3" from dual
```